# How do I create .js files for a CLI on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm starting to create a CLI for process automation, but I have no idea how to create .js .css .styl files on the user who will run "Cli-command start", does anyone know if they use FS or some other tools for this?

Comment: you have to use fs only for creating a file be it of any sort

Comment: no use fs, nothing else